# Merge Columns in Pandas while keeping empty values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes(#'s are changed to make it easier)

let's say:

print(a)
Sector    Still Have
0      Energy  10000
1  Index Fund  20000
2  Technology  20000
3   Utilities   5000

print(b)
Sector                  Ideal Mrkt Value
0      Communications      15000
1   Consumer Cyclical      20000
2  Consumer Defensive      10000
3              Energy      5000
4          Healthcare      10000
5          Index Fund      25000
6           Materials      5000
7          Technology      100000
8           Utilities      5000

I want to merge a and b on sector so that way it would result in:
Sector            Ideal Mrkt Value    Still Have
0      Communications      15000       0
1   Consumer Cyclical      20000       0
2  Consumer Defensive      10000       0
3              Energy      5000        10000
4          Healthcare      10000       0
5          Index Fund      25000       20000
6           Materials      5000        0
7          Technology      100000      20000
8           Utilities      5000        5000

my current code is:

```
x = pd.merge(a,b, on='Sector', how='inner')
```

The problem is that when this runs: I get only the merged tables when both of the same sector exists in both tables. Is there a way to get it to add the still have column and when it doesn't have a value it inputs 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just got it to work, I needed to use a left merge:

x = a.merge(b, how='left', left_on='Sector', right_on='Sector')